# Controller not found in slim 3

Tags: php, routes, controller, slim-3

I am new to slim,so please bear with me.
I have project structure like

```
\slim
　　\public
　　　　index.php
　　　　
　　\src
　　　　\controllers
         \reports
　　　　　　  BillingReportController.php
       \routes
         router.php
       \config
         db.php
```

But whenever I call the controller via route it gives me below error

"PHP Fatal error:  Class 'src\controllers\reports\BillingReportController' not found in /var/www/html/apimod/public/index.php on line 13"

As for the line mentioned in error the snippet is as follows.

**index.php**

```
$container = $app->getContainer();
$container['BillingReportController'] = function($container){
    return new \src\controllers\reports\BillingReportController;
};
```

**router.php**

```
$app->group('/report', function() use ($app) {

  $app->get('/billing', 'BillingReportController:billing');
});
```

**BillingReportController.php**

```
namespace src\controllers\BillingReportController;

class BillingReportController{
    public function billing($request, $response){
        //my code goes here
    }
}
```

Can anyone please point out the error.

Comment: Think the namespace of your controller is incorrect `namespace src\controllers\BillingReportController`.

Comment: What should I use then?

Comment: As its in a directory called reports, perhaps `src\controllers\reports`

Comment: no joy. error still persists.

Answer (score 0):

You must've to use autoloading in your composer. something like this.

```
"autoload": {
"psr-4": {
  "src\\": "src"
 }
}
```

then in your terminal enter this command

```
composer dump-autoload
```

it should fix your problem